# JVM problem while running eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse

I have installed Java 9 JDK on my Ubuntu. Now I need to install Eclipse. I have downloaded and extracted Eclipse Mars to `/opt` folder. When I started eclipse from console I got error:

```
gedas@gedas-Latitude-E5450:/opt$ cd eclipse
g@g-Latitude-E5450:/opt/eclipse$ ./eclipse 
Unrecognized VM option 'MaxPermSize=256m'
Error: Could not create the Java Virtual Machine.
Error: A fatal exception has occurred. Program will exit.
g@g-Latitude-E5450:/opt/eclipse$
```

And message box:

```
JVM terminated. Exit code=1
/usr/bin/java
-Dosgi.requiredJavaVersion=1.7
-XX:MaxPermSize=256m
-Xms256m
-Xmx1024m
-jar /opt/eclipse//plugins/org.eclipse.equinox.launcher_1.3.100.v20150511-1540.jar
-os linux
-ws gtk
-arch x86_64
-showsplash /opt/eclipse//plugins/org.eclipse.platform_4.5.2.v20160212-1500/splash.bmp
-launcher /opt/eclipse/eclipse
-name Eclipse
--launcher.library /opt/eclipse//plugins/org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.gtk.linux.x86_64_1.1.300.v20150602-1417/eclipse_1612.so
-startup /opt/eclipse//plugins/org.eclipse.equinox.launcher_1.3.100.v20150511-1540.jar
--launcher.appendVmargs
-exitdata 121800e
-product org.eclipse.epp.package.cpp.product
-vm /usr/bin/java
-vmargs
-Dosgi.requiredJavaVersion=1.7
-XX:MaxPermSize=256m
-Xms256m
-Xmx1024m
-jar /opt/eclipse//plugins/org.eclipse.equinox.launcher_1.3.100.v20150511-1540.jar
```

`java -version` returns

```
java version "9-ea"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 9-ea+111)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 9-ea+111, mixed mode)
```

How to fix this problem?

Comment: Java 9 is planned to be released finally in 2017, so if you use Java 9, that's an early development version. You have to expect encountering many bugs in that and I'm afraid we can't help you with that here. File a bug report against your Java build and talk directly to the developers. We can't fix their code from here, and that's probably the only way to solve the problem.

Comment: So, I need to remove java 9 and place java 8. But how to remove java 9 now?

Comment: That depends on how you installed it.

Comment: Something like that:                      sudo apt-get updatesudo add-apt-repository ppa:webupd8team/java

                      sudo add-apt-repository ppa:webupd8team/java

                      sudo apt-get install oracle-java9-installer

Comment: I would recommend you to install the `ppa-purge` tool and let it remove that entire java PPA together with all packages from it. I am not sure if simply purging the installer package (`sudo apt-get purge oracle-java9-installer`)would also remove the real Java installation.

Answer (score 2):

so solution is you have to  change default jdk by following command

`sudo update-alternatives --config java`

And select different entry for jdk path eg:- 1 or 2 or 3 any and enter
you have to change entry from default to some different jdk

This will work 100%

Comment: Best solution ! Instead of removing the JDK or waiting for a Eclipse dev release, this fixes the problem without having to loose JShell ! +1111

Answer (score 1):

This is probably Eclipse bug [489958](https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=489958) which is marked as being fixed in Eclipse Neon milestone 7 (4.6M7) which is not yet available.

Eclipse Mars is really intended to be used with the current Java 8 release rather than Java 9 early access releases.